# Send an image from server to canvas on a page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, file-upload, html5-canvas

- I have a form on *page A*.
- I upload an image and post it to server.
- Server uploads the image and redirects the user to *page B*.
- I have a canvas on *page B* on which I want to draw that image using JavaScript.

**Question:**

- How can the server send the image to *page B*?

Comment: Why javascript? do you want the image to be drawn when the page  loads, you can draw that by passing the image URL where you upload the image

Comment: when you upload the image you surely save the path to the new image somewhere in your database. So when you redirect just include the id, the filename, whatever in that redirect request.

Comment: I need to draw the image on canvas using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

here is my idea to to get path from server

```
<form action="pageA.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

*pageA.php*:

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    $todir = "uploads/";
    $file = $tooir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $_SESSION['img']=$todir;
    $checkimg = 1;
    $imageType = strtolower(pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $checkimg  = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $checkimg  = 0;
        }if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $file)) {
        $up=1 ;  
        $_SESSION['img']=$todir; 
        $_SESSION['up']=$up;
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
     header("location:./pageB.php");

    } else {
up=o;// checking whether file is uploaded
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

*pageB:*(**write `session_start()` at top & `script` at bottom of the page**)

```
<?php
  session_Start();
  if($_SESSION['up'])
   {
     echo "<script>window.onload = function() {
    var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context=c.getContext('2d');
    var image=document.getElementById('draw');
    ctx.drawImage(image,10,10);
    };</script><img src=$_SESSION['img'] id=draw > <canvas id=myCanvas> </canvas>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".

Comment: @ZainEjaz click the tick mark and upvote if you are satisfied with my answer